# Como selecionar todos os caracteres exceto algumas palavras específicas usando regex?

Tags: regex

Bom dia a todos,

Gostaria de executar uma busca em uma string por algumas sequências de caracteres específicas, porém no projeto que estamos trabalhando não temos acesso a nenhuma função `find` ou similar, somente a uma função de substituição baseada em expressão regular (algo do tipo `replace(string, regex, replacement)`).

A ideia então seria a seguinte: selecionar todos os caracteres EXCETO as sequências que eu quero achar. Assim, eu removeria esses caracteres não desejados e compararia com o que eu quero encontrar.

Exemplo (não é nenhuma linguagem específica):

```
string expReg = ??????;
string texto = "xxxxxxxxboloxxxxxxxfarinhaxxxxxxacucarxxxx";
string busca = replace(texto, expReg, "");
if(busca == "bolofarinhaacucar"){
    return("Sucesso");
}
```

Por sorte as palavras que precisamos encontrar precisam estar na ordem definida, então não seria necessário incluir todas as permutações.

Tentamos encontrar alguma solução usando expressões regulares, mas sempre esbarramos no problema de que o lookbehind positivo `(?<=ABC)` não é suportado em Javascript.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: qual linguagem? Javascript?

Comment: Só por curiosidade: que linguagem é essa que não tem um find mas tem replace?

Comment: Na realidade é um script utilizado por um sistema na empresa onde trabalho. Também achamos estranho ele não dar suporte a find, mas dar suporte a replace (ainda por cima com expressões regulares!), mas fazer o que, né...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seria bom sabe a linguagem que você está trabalhando pra saber uma forma mais eficiente de te ajudar já que negar palavra em regex não é fácil

http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/negar-palavra.html#5_3

Como você falou que sempre vai ser essas palavras específicas pode fazer algo assim

```
expReg = "\w+(bolo)\w+(farinha)\w+(acucar)\w+"

string texto = "xxxxxxxxboloxxxxxxxfarinhaxxxxxxacucarxxxx";
string busca = replace(texto, expReg, "$1$2$3"); //substitui pelo grupo 1, 2 e 3
```

--
Pode teste aqui: https://regex101.com/r/oP3kU3/1

Comment: Eu realmente não sabia que havia essa dificuldade em negar palavras em regex. Porém essa solução é a que mais se aproxima do que a gente estava procurando. Só teve um detalhe que eu esqueci de mencionar: pode haver espaços entre as palavras, então o `\w+` não funcionaria. Mas neste caso é só substituir por `\D+` ou ainda `.*` que funciona corretamente. Obrigado!

Comment: se funcionou ta blz =D

Answer (score 3):

Para retirar um determinado caractere de uma sequência basta fazer a seguinte substituição (exemplo em Javascript):

```js
var texto = 'xxxxxxxxboloxxxxxxxfarinhaxxxxxxacucarxxxx';

var expReg = /([x]+)/g; // Vai procurar por uma ou mais ocorrências de "x"
var busca = texto.replace(expReg, '');

if(busca == "bolofarinhaacucar"){
    console.log("Sucesso");
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b7684456/)</kbd>

Para negar a correspondência(*match*) de determinados caracteres basta usar a [classe de caracteres negados](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) usando `^` no início da classe.

```js
var texto = 'xxxxxxxxboloxxxxxxxfarinhaxxxxxxacucarxxxx';

var expReg = /([^x]+)/g;
var buscaArray = texto.match(expReg, '').toString(); // match retorna um array com os valores encontrados
var busca = buscaArray.split(",").join(""); // Transformamos para string para poder comparar

if(busca == "bolofarinhaacucar"){
    console.log("Sucesso");
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uc9Lxfe2/)</kbd>

Talvez a sintaxe mude dependendo da *engine* utilizada. [**Aqui**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines)(*em inglês*) mostra uma comparação entre as *engines* de expressões regulares.

Comment: Se tiver o `x` no meio da palavra vai dar problema.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti Acho que não, pois se tiver um *x* em `farxinha` é retornado `far` e `inha`.

Comment: Mas é esse o problema. Eu coloquei xxxx, mas poderia ser qualquer caractere, por exemplo: `"leitebolofarinhaovosacucar"`. E se for tirar todos os caracteres (`[a-z]`), também afetaria as palavras que vamos buscar.